# Put UISearchBar in UINavigationBar when Title, Left button and Right button are already there

Tags: iphone, swift, storyboard, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Is it possible to add UISearchBar in UINavigationBar when it is already having a title, left and right bar buttons to display? I will display search in a second line just below the title if it is possible to include it in the UINavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

You can add `uiview` inside the middle of the `navigationbar` and configure the title and search bar there at accordingly rest left and right button will remain as it is.